# How can I close all modals and stacks currently open?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a screen "Home" with a "Product page" which is pushed onto the stack in which I have a modal "Settings" open. When pressing a button (delete) I would like to close all modals and pop all screens from the stack to go back to "Home".

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Navigation.dismissAllModals()](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/modal#dismissallmodals) to close all currently displayed modals.

To pop all screens pushed into a stack, assign that stack a unique id and call `Navigation.popToRoot('STACK_ID')`. [Link to popToRoot in the docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/stack#poptoroot) and here you can read [how to interact with a stack by a predefined id](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/stack#interact-with-the-stack-by-a-predefined-id).

Comment: Where do we import this Navigation from?